# Creating a dynamic function with a split function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can not get it done. I hope someone can help me out with this.

```
modus.value.getCurrentDataPath = sale.id (STRING)
```

OR

```
modus.value.getCurrentDataPath = id (STRING)
```

In the example below I want to check if `modus.value.getCurrentDataPath` includes a . (dot) or not. In the end I want to create a `router.push{()}`

```
const route1 = [] as any;
if (modus.value.getCurrentDataPath.includes('.')) {
 const test = modus.value.getCurrentDataPath.split('.')
 let i;
 for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
   route1.push(test[i])
 }
} else {
 route1.push(modus.value.getCurrentDataPath);
}
    router.push({ path: route.path + '/' + getCurrent.value[route1] });
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. He cannot read the 2 split strings.

It should be: getCurrent.value.sale.id

How to fix this? I want to get it working for both. With dot and without dot. In one router.push.

Comment: please add missing parts, like `modus` or `route`.

Comment: I provided what modus.value.getCurrentDataPath is. route.path is standard Vue (nothing to show). The question is al about to create getCurrent.value.id or getCurrent.value.sale.id

Comment: If `Vue` is part of the question - then you should remember to add that as a tag. It's important information. :)